# Rails 4 - cannot load such file -- rich (LoadError) - After removing gem from gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've removed a gem from my gemfile (specifically this [gem](https://github.com/bastiaanterhorst/rich)). I've run `bundle update`. I can't start the server or migrate db because of this error I now get: `` /lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require': cannot load such file -- rich (LoadError) ``

Comment: Find all references to `rich` in your code and remove them if necessary. Especially look for initialisers and assets. (or manual require somewhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had trouble removing this gem as well. Simply run a search in your application to find all references to the gem and remove them. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find any other way other than manual removal.